# how can i control window.location.hash

Tags: jquery

I have navigation with following values:

```
<a href="#home" id="home" class="goto">Home</a>
<a href="#profile" id="profile" class="goto">Profile</a>
<a href="#account" id="account" class="goto">Account</a>
<a href="#feedback" id="feed" class="goto">Feedback</a><br><br><div id="target"></div>
```

Now I have the following function:

```
$(".goto").live("click", function(){
var goto = $(this).attr("id");
 $.post(goto+".php", {}, function(data){
$("#target").html(data);
});

});
```

It is working fine but when I hit back on browser it is not doing anything, while I want on hitting back or forward on browser content should change with above mentioned function.

Please don't divert me to another similar question or page let me know the exact solution.

Comment: "Please don't divert me to another similar question or page let me know the exact solution"  Umm, excuse me?  I was planning on helping you until I read this smartass remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all browsers don't support it yet, I'd grab the [hashchange plugin by Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/), then your can just add:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
  $(location.hash).click();
});
```

If you hash was say `#home` after hitting the back button, this would trigger the `click` handler for that anchor, causing your current handler to execute and load that content.  Also if you don't need to POST, (since you're not passing any variables), you can simplify your `click` handler as well, like this:

```
$(".goto").live("click", function(){
  $("#target").load(this.id+".php");
});
```

Comment: `$(location.hash)`  Clever. :)